# How to change a value in a closure and print it in another? Rust - gtk

Tags: rust, closures, gtk

While trying to write a basic **Rust gtk** application, I was stuck not being able to retrive a value and print it from an entry. It boils down to the inability to change and then display the value in two different closures, associated to two different signals.

A bit of searching led me to `RefCell` which seems to be needed to do such a thing, but still I haven't got any success.

What I'd like to achive looks somehow like this:

```rust
    let mut x: i32 = 0;

    btn.connect_clicked(clone!(@weak lbl => move |_|{
        lbl.set_text("btn1 clicked");
        x = 1;
    }));

    btn2.connect_clicked(clone!(@weak lbl => move |_|{
        lbl.set_text("btn2 clicked");
        println!("stored value of x is {}", x);
    }));
```

To my understanding, I cannot assign a new value to x in the first closure because of this being an `Fn` one, but what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to wrap your variable in `Rc<T>`. It is a shared pointer type which uses reference counting to decide when to de-allocate the object. You need it because you have to guarantee that the reference to the object will remain valid for as long as some component of your app still holds it.

As you've already discovered, you will also need to use the [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html#refcellt-and-the-interior-mutability-pattern) pattern in order to change the value, because `Rc` does not allow mutation.

So at the end you should have:

```rust
let x = Rc::new(RefCell::new(0));
```

Now you should clone that `Rc` and use the clone inside  the closure:

```
let x1 = Rc::clone(x);
btn.connect_clicked(clone!(@weak lbl => move |_|{
    lbl.set_text("btn1 clicked");
    *x1.borrow_mut() = 1;
}));

let x2 = Rc::clone(x);
btn2.connect_clicked(clone!(@weak lbl => move |_|{
    lbl.set_text("btn2 clicked");
    println!("stored value of x is {}", x2.borrow());
}));
```

This should work as long as you do not try to send the Rc to another thread and mutate the value concurrently. For multi-threaded interior mutability you should use `Arc<Mutex<T>>` instead.

Comment: I see, I missed the use of `Rc`. Thank you very much.
Guess I can use the `clone!` macro to keep the same name in all the signal handlers